# Drupal permissions and role(own group content)

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-permissions

I'm working on my drupal website.

I need that Manager(a custom user role) and Publisher(a custom use role) can upload documents (a custom content type) and until here it's all ok.

Then i need also that for example there is:

user A that is a manager

user B is a publisher

user C is publisher

I want assign the possibility for A to see the documents uploaded by B, but not C documents.

How i can do it ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking from a `download` perspective view, hope the [Private files download permission](https://drupal.org/project/private_files_download_permission) module can do the trick for u mate.It has a feature that allows downloads based on the `user roles` etc.You might also find the below link useful mate.. :)

[Drupal 7: how to restrict file access to specific user roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849928/drupal-7-how-to-restrict-file-access-to-specific-user-roles)

You might also check if the [File Entity Permission](https://drupal.org/project/file_entity_perms) suits your purpose.This module allows you to set who can view or download a file.