# In drupal 7 user access only files assigned to him

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Hello I want to user in system have files that only that registered user can open. And there is no other access to it.

Can it be done in Drupal 7 like so: configuration->account settings add new type as file and set it as private? Or there is other better way to achieve that ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drupal 7: how to restrict file access to specific user roles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849928/drupal-7-how-to-restrict-file-access-to-specific-user-roles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it without modules, see this page:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1792780

Or here are a couple of modules:
https://www.drupal.org/project/file_access
https://www.drupal.org/project/private_files_download_permission

Answer (score 0):

Along with making storing the files in a private folder on your server, try the content access module: https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access

It creates a view own permission on a content type that will allow you to grant view permissions on content only for the owner.  You would just create a new content type for this type of file and then grant the proper access for that new content type.  It also says in the documentation that the module allows for access control not only at the content type level, but also at the node level.